# How can I have the user only add their @name instead of entire Twitter link in a url_field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In my Rails app I have a user model (Devise) with url_field for Twitter.

Right now I have this in my show page:

```
<%= link_to @deal.user.company_twitter, @deal.user.company_twitter, :class => "comp_twitter" %>
```

It shows the entire link in the show page (even `http://`), that's because my url_field makes the user add "http://" or it won't validate the link.

I want the user to only add their "@name" instead of the whole Twitter link when creating their profile. I would also want to show only the @name instead of the Twitter link in the "show" page. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply don't use an `url_field`, but a regular `string` database field, like `twitter_username`. When signing up, let the user enter their username, e.g. `foo`.

For getting the real URL to the Twitter account, create a new method in your `user.rb` model:

```
def twitter_url
  "http://twitter.com/#{self.twitter_username}"
end
```

The advantage is that at this point, in your model, you can include a custom validation that would check if this URL really exists after the user has submitted their `twitter_username`.

Finally, use that in your view instead of just the URL:

```
<%= link_to "@#{@user.twitter_username}", @user.twitter_url %>
```

This would render:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/foo">@foo</a>
```